# Modifying custom designs for chapter and appendix heading pages

Tags: sectioning, formatting, appendices

I have made to following book class MWE that uses [this](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html) template for making the chapter heading pages look pretty.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

%%%%%
% v chapter heading style from http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html
%%%%
\makeatletter
 \def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill 
 \kern \z@}
 \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \reset@font
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ 
    \begin{flushright}
  \reset@font \scshape \bfseries \Huge \thechapter \par
\end{flushright}
\hrule
\begin{flushright}
  \reset@font \LARGE \strut #1\strut \par
\end{flushright}
\vskip 100\p@
}}
 \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \reset@font
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ 
    \begin{flushright}
      \reset@font \scshape \bfseries \Huge \vphantom{\thechapter} \par
    \end{flushright}
    \hrule
    \begin{flushright}
      \reset@font \LARGE \strut #1\strut \par
    \end{flushright}
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

  \chapter{title of this chapter}

some text

\begin{appendices}

  \chapter{Title of this appendix}\label{apx:f}

  \section{an appendix section}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Currently this produces simple numbers for chapter headings (i.e. "1" instead of "Chapter 1"). This is what I want.

It also does a similar trick to appendices (i.e. "A" instead of "Appendix A"). I don't want this.

How can I change the script to give me appendix titles like: "Appendix A"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that with the `apptools` package, which defines booleans and conditional related with being in an appendix. B.t.w., to have bold small caps with Computer Modern, you have to load `cm-super`, i.e. load the `T1` font encoding:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{apptools}

%%%%%
% v chapter heading style from http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html
%%%%
\makeatletter
 \def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill
 \kern \z@}
 \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \reset@font
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@
    \begin{flushright}
  \reset@font \scshape \bfseries \Huge\IfAppendix{Appendix}{} \thechapter \par
\end{flushright}
\hrule
\begin{flushright}
  \reset@font \LARGE \strut #1\strut \par
\end{flushright}
\vskip 100\p@
}}
 \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \reset@font
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@
    \begin{flushright}
      \reset@font \scshape \bfseries \Huge\vphantom{\thechapter} \par%
    \end{flushright}
    \hrule
    \begin{flushright}
      \reset@font \LARGE \strut #1\strut \par
    \end{flushright}
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
\makeatother
%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

  \chapter{title of this chapter}

some text

\begin{appendices} \appendixtrue

  \chapter{Title of this appendix}\label{apx:f}

  \section{An appendix section}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: excellent wizardry!