# Different custom chapter headings and appendix headings

Tags: sectioning, formatting, appendices, appendix

I am writing my thesis with bookdown in r. I have created custom chapter headings however I would like to change the chapter headings in the appendix.

I'm sorry, I have tried to create a minimal working example but have been unable to get the pdf to render. However this is the current preamble text that works and refers to the chapter headings:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\usepackage{apptools}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica}

\newcommand\headerdisplay[1]{%
\huge % title in box
\vskip-1\baselineskip
\filcenter{#1}%
\vskip-1\baselineskip
}

\NewCoffin\mytmpa
\NewCoffin\mytmpb
\newcommand\placeabove[3][0pt]{%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\mytmpa{#2}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\mytmpb{#3}%
\JoinCoffins*\mytmpb[hc,t]\mytmpa[hc,b](0pt,#1)%
\TypesetCoffin\mytmpb
}
      
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
{\setlength\fboxrule{2pt}\color{black}\headingfont\bfseries\FrameSep 20pt\FrameRule=4pt}
{\filcenter\placeabove[1\baselineskip]{\huge Chapter}{\huge\enspace\thechapter\enspace}}
{10pt}
{\headerdisplay}
```

[image]

I have tried to adapt the code using `\IfAppendix` which I found in this very similar question [Modifying custom designs for chapter and appendix heading pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506916/modifying-custom-designs-for-chapter-and-appendix-heading-pages).

The closest I have managed to get is using

`{\filcenter\placeabove[1\baselineskip]{\huge\IfAppendix{Appendix}{}Chapter}{\huge\enspace\thechapter\enspace}}`

[image]

I realise this is far from an ideally structured question, but after several hours, I have not been able to produce a neat example and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was incomplete and when I tried to add the `\documentclass...` etc it didn't work for me. Below is what I eventually got to work.

```
% apptitleprob.tex SE 506916

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\usepackage{apptools}
%\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica}
\newcommand{\headingfont}{}

\newcommand\headerdisplay[1]{%
\huge % title in box
\vskip-1\baselineskip
\filcenter{#1}%
\vskip-1\baselineskip
}

\NewCoffin\mytmpa
\NewCoffin\mytmpb
\newcommand\placeabove[3][0pt]{%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\mytmpa{#2}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\mytmpb{#3}%
\JoinCoffins*\mytmpb[hc,t]\mytmpa[hc,b](0pt,#1)%
\TypesetCoffin\mytmpb
}
      
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
{\setlength\fboxrule{2pt}\color{black}\headingfont\bfseries\FrameSep 20pt\FrameRule=4pt}
%{\filcenter\placeabove[1\baselineskip]{\huge Chapter}{\huge\enspace\thechapter\enspace}}
{\filcenter\placeabove[1\baselineskip]{\huge\IfAppendix{Appendix}{Chapter}}{\huge\enspace\thechapter\enspace}}
{10pt}
{\headerdisplay}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{First appendix}
\chapter{Second appendix}
\end{document}
```

Note the change that I made to your `{\filcenter\placeabove...` line of code.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Peter!